# No match for the operator c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have to write a function that appends vector b to vector a (a= 1234 b=567, output=1234567). Im having trouble with this since im kinda new to this stuff but my problem is that i get the error "no match for operator << " on line 37 which is where i wrote cout << merge. Im not even sure if im doing the program correctly but i just want to know why im getting this error and any help on the program would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> merge(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
  int n = a.size();
  int m = b.size();
  vector<int> c;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n || i < m; i++)
  {
     if (i < n)
       {
         c.push_back(a[i]);
       }
     if (i < m)
      {
         c.push_back(b[i]);
      }
  }
  return c;
 }

int main ()
{
  vector<int> v1(4,1);
  vector<int> v2(3,2);

  cout << merge (v1,v2) <<endl;;


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no predefined operator << for class std::vector. You could use the range based for statement for example.

```
for ( int x : merge( a, b ) ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Also merge is wrong. It could be defined like

```
std::vector<int> merge( const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b )
{
    std::vector<int> c( a.begin(), a.end() );

    c.insert( c.end(), b.begin(), b.end() );

    return c;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> merge( const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b )
{
    std::vector<int> c( a.begin(), a.end() );

    c.insert( c.end(), b.begin(), b.end() );

    return c;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1( 4, 1 );
    std::vector<int> v2( 3, 2 );

    for ( int x : merge( v1, v2 ) ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

If you may not by some reason use the insert method then you can write the function the following way

```
std::vector<int> merge( const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b )
{
    std::vector<int> c;
    c.reserve( a.size() + b.size() );

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) c.push_back( a[i] );
    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < b.size(); i++ ) c.push_back( b[i] );

    return c;
}
```

Comment: is there another way to do it other than the insert method? cuz i havent learned that and i dont want to include something i didnt learn in class

Comment: @darkphantom1 What is the problem with the insert method? I will uodate my post now. See it.

Comment: i havent learned that method in class so i dont want to use it unless there isnt any other way but im sure there is

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << merge (v1,v2) <<endl;
```

Because operator<< does not know how to print vector.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is not overloaded for `std::vector<int>`. Write the overload yourself:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<T> const& xs) {
    for (auto&& x : xs) {
        stream << x << ", ";
    }
    return stream;
}
```